# Set row height of emtpy rows to 0 in tabular

Tags: tables, spacing

I use some software that spits out latex tables. Sometimes whole rows are empty, only consisting of `& & & \\`. I want these rows to take up no space, but can't alter any code within these rows.

Is there a way to make the row height content dependent, so that these rows will vanish?

Here a small MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  First & row \\
  Second & row \\
  & \\
  Fourth & row to follow immediately, since the third was empty \\
  \shortstack{Fifth \\ row} & seems to adjust just fine as it is larger
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: not easily in TeX, simpler to just clean up the source with perl or sed or something. the row height is forced by a `\strut` in the _first_ cell in the row so by the time you get to the last it's a bit late to do anything.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, does the same hold true if was able to replace `& & \\ ` with `\somecommand & \somecommand & \somecommand \\ ` ?

Comment: yes you just need something like `sed -i -e '^[ &]*\\\\$'` to remove all lines that just consist of `&` and space followed by `\\ `. Nothing you can do in TeX is likely to be simpler or more robust.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Unfortunately sed doesn't fit into the workflow. My comment-question was rather whether such commands would make it easier.

Comment: not really: honestly it's really quite hard to do that from tex especially if there is any chance the tables have `\multicolumn` you'd have to redefine tabular internals (which are different depending if `array` package is loaded or not) and almost certainly conflict with some package somewhere.

Comment: You can add a `[-\normalbaselineskip]` to the end of the blank line, as in `Second & row\\
&\\[-\normalbaselineskip]
Fourth & row to follow immediately, since the thrid was emp\\
`, if that fits with your workflow...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes that's cheating:-) If you can change the in-document markup you could simply not add the blank row. Also `\normalbaselineskip` won't be enough if `\arraystretch` has been used.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I would gladly cheat death!  The same applied to LaTeX.